# in Hbase,Try to minimize row and column sizes,why?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata, nosql

Looking at: http://hbase.apache.org/1.2/book.html#rowkey.design

I cannot understand `36.3`. Try to minimize row and column sizes, why? This chapter is difficult for me to understand. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I totally disagree with closing this question as off-topic. How is it not clear?!

Answer (score 1):

The docs is talking about key length and column name length size important which was found to matter in context of indexes in hbase ( [jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-3551?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13005272#comment-13005272)).
If key size is large then the index size also become big. Systems depending upon  indexing always prefer to keep the indexes in memory since it would be really bad to hit the 
disk for index access. If the index size becomes unnecessarily high (resulting in high JVM heap ) it impacts performance.

Comment: excuse me ,what is meaning of indexes in hbase?thank you

Comment: In HBase only the keys ( consisting of the rowkey, column
qualifier, and timestamp) are indexed in HBase tables.The only way to access a particular row is through the rowkey. Indexing
the qualifier and timestamp lets you skip to the right column without scanning all
the previous columns in that row. For further info you can refer to http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/06/hbase-io-hfile-input-output/